# virtual grouping by color using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a html table where I would like to visually group data based on a certain column.

```css
body {
  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
th{
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <th>Item No</th>
  <th>Item Name</th>
  <th>Qty</th>
  <th>Expiry Date</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>01-Mar-2016</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>25-Mar-2016</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>05-Apr-2016</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>01-Jan-2016</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>01-Mar-2016</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>DEF</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>01-Mar-2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>PQR</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>05-Mar-2016</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>PQR</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>01-Nov-2016</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>IJK</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>15-May-2016</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>LMN</td>
    <td>99</td>
    <td>31-Dec-2016</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In this example I would like to have same color all rows which have similar Item Nos. and color needs to be different for different groups and there can be n no. of groups or rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an array of colors having `.length` equal to largest item id number, using `.each()` to iterate `tr` elements,  `.text()` of first `td` element to reference index of array containing colors to set

```
var colors = ["dodgerblue", "gold", "tan", "orange", "gray", "green"]

$("tr").each(function(i, el) {
  var item = $("td:first", this).text();
  $(this).css("background", colors[item -1])
})
```

```js
var colors = ["dodgerblue", "gold", "tan", "orange", "gray", "green"];

$("tr").each(function(i, el) {
  var item = $("td:first", this).text();
  $(this).css("background", colors[item -1])
})
```

```css
body {
  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Item No</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Expiry Date</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>01-Mar-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>25-Mar-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>05-Apr-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>01-Jan-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>01-Mar-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>DEF</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>01-Mar-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>PQR</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>05-Mar-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>PQR</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>01-Nov-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>IJK</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>15-May-2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>LMN</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td>31-Dec-2016</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5t1oo1zm/8/

Comment: Although it does what I asked but it has a flaw. The color is set based on the item no index in the array, what if item no starts from 10k count? I.e. if I change item no 1 to 1000 the rows will not have any color.

Comment: @NikhilGupta _"The color is set based on the item no index in the array, what if item no starts from 10k count?"_ ? Not certain interpret _"what if item no starts from 10k count"_ correctly ? Can fork jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5t1oo1zm/8/ to demonstrate ? Color selection is based on text of first `td` element with `tr`

Comment: Plz check this https://jsfiddle.net/5t1oo1zm/59/ now color coding gets removed from top 3 rows having item no 11100.

Comment: @NikhilGupta Substitute defining `colors` as an object for an array https://jsfiddle.net/5t1oo1zm/60/

Comment: Also for random color generation I will play around with following '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16); let's c if we in incorporate this in ur example.

Comment: For a start this is good but this is not generic. Here we need to define/assign item no to color array to be used later which is not feasible as there could be 5K items.

Comment: @NikhilGupta _"Here we need to define/assign item no to color array to be used later which is not feasible as there could be 5K items."_ does not appear at text of original Question ? Used `html` provided at Question, which contains six item numbers  for stacksnippets to demonstrate a possible approach

Comment: Sure, ans to my example has been provided but m just saying its not generic enough. Anyways thanks for the help. Will try and find my way out.

Comment: @NikhilGupta No worries. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I have modified guest271314's answer to better suit your n number of groups.  Having a list of predefined colors to the n amount is not reasonable and would eventually be displeasing to the eye.  I recommend alternating between a set of colors.

**SCRIPT**

```
var colors = ["dodgerblue", "gold", "tan", "orange", "gray", "green"]

$("tr").each(function(i, el) {
  var item = $("td:first", this).text();
    $(this).css("background", colors[item%7]);    
});
```

See a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5t1oo1zm/56/

Comment: Although it does what I asked but it has a flaw. The color is set based on the item no index in the array, what if item no starts from 10k count? I.e. if I change item no 1 to 1000 the rows will not have any color.